# Representing filesystem table

Tags: python, filesystems

I’m working on simple class something like “in memory  linux-like filesystem” for educational purposes. Files will be as StringIO objects. I can’t make decision how to implement files-folders hierarchy type in Python. I’m thinking about using list of objects with fields: type, name, parent what else? Maybe I should look for trees and graphs.

### Update:

There will be these methods:

new_dir(path), 
dir_list(path), 
is_file(path), 
is_dir(path), remove(path), 
read(file_descr), 
file_descr open(file_path, mode=w|r), 
close(file_descr), 
write(file_descr, str)

Comment: This question is a bit too broad for stackoverflow and is quite open-ended. Try to ask a very specific question so that it's clear about what to answer.

Comment: I think the question is okay but open ended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly possible to represent a tree as a nested set of lists. However, since entries are typically indexed by name, and a directory is generally considered to be unordered, nested dictionaries would make many operations faster and easier to write.

I wouldn't store the parent for each entry though, that's implicit from its position in the hierarchy.

Also, if you want your virtual file system to efficiently support [hard links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link), you need to separate a file's contents from the directory hierarchy. That way, you can re-use the contents by giving each piece of content any number of names, which is what hard linking does.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try using [networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/). You just have to intutive to adapt it to use with files and folder.

A simple example

```
import os,networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()
for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    bname = os.path.split(path)
    for f in files:
        G.add_edge(bname,f)
# Now do what ever you want with the Graph
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first ask the question: What operations should my "file system" support?

Based on the answer you select the data representation.

For example, if you choose to support only `create` and `delete` and the order of the files in  the dictionary is not important, then select a python dictionary. A dictionary will map a file name (sub path name) to either a dictionary or the file container object.

Answer (score 0):

What's the API of the filestore? Do you want to keep creation, modification and access times? Presumably the primary lookup will be by file name. Are any other retrieval operations anticipated?

If only lookup by name is required then one possible representation is to map the filestore root directory on to a Python dict. Each entry's key will be the filename, and the value will either be a StringIO object (hint: in Python 2 use cStringIO for better performance if it becomes an issue) or another dict. The StringIO objects represent your files, the dicts represent subdirectories.

So, to access any path you split it up into its constituent components (using `.split("/")`) and then use each to look up a successive element. Any KeyError exceptions imply "File or directory not found," as would any attempts to index a StringIO object (I'm too lazy to verify the specific exception).

If you want to implement greater detail then you would replace the StringIO objects and dicts with instances of some "filestore object" class. You could call it a "link" (since that's what it models: A Linux hard link). The various attributes of this object can easily be manipulated to keep the file attributes up to date, and the `.data` attribute can be either a StringIO object or a dict as before.

Overall I would prefer the second solution, since then it's easy to implement methods that do things like keep access times up to date by updating them as the operations are performed, but as I said much depends on the level of detail you want to provide.